# iOS : Firebase notification not working for user segment

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-notifications

I recently upgraded my project to Swift3 and updated Firebase pod to version 4.0.0. After resolving all the errors and warnings, when I tried to send push notification from console. I found the single device push notification sending is working fine. However, sending to specific user segment is not; which I need most for my application. 
While sending push to user segment I am simply checking the iOS bundle id and trying to send all of the devices in which the app is installed.

Comment: Using the Console's push notification for specific devices (user segment) should work if sending to a specific device works. How do you know that user segment doesn't work? Perhaps the push is just not being received, remember a push notification is not 100% reliable, it can be delayed and even be failed to be received. :) Ps. remember to select one answer that answers your question.

Comment: @Glenn I did wanted to upvote your previous question's answer but 
I believe I don't have enough credits to do so. :(

Comment: With regards to the above question, I am continuously trying to send notification to the bundle id (as user segment) but I never receive the notification. But on contrary to it while sending using FCM token to single device it works.

Comment: You can select an answer though. Anyways, I never had such problem when pushing using user segment. Have you double checked your projects' bundle ids? Check every ids of your project registered in any of your certificates, developer.apple.com, firebase, google plist in Xcode, Xcode, etc...

Comment: @HeckylTechnologies, i am facing same problem, have you got any solution then please share with us

Comment: I am also facing same problem ...

Comment: I also have the same problem.

Comment: same problem my side

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure of this is what did it but mine started working after I added my App Store ID to the GoogleService-Info.plist section of my Firebase project. Individual device notifications always worked but I could never get "bulk" notifications to work properly until I added that.

I didn't have to redownload the .plist file and add it to my app either. Simply adding the ID to the Firebase configuration page appears to have made it work.